# How do I treat unmet peer dependency as an error in Yarn?

Tags: yarnpkg

When I run `yarn` on my project, I get a warning during the linking phase stating:

```
warning " > foo@1.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "bar@^2.0.0"
```

After going through and cleaning these warnings up, I would like to prevent future regressions like this by making these fail the install step in our dev and CI environments.  Does yarn provide any mechanism to do this (i.e. CLI arguments or config file changes) or do I need to write something to parse the output?

Comment: You're referring to Yarn as in the NPM alternative, correct?

Comment: @CoryCoolguy Yes.

Comment: Excellent  here's a relevant retag proposal -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn

Comment: Related Github issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8092

Answer (score 4):

Yarn v2 has [logFilters](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#logFilters) which make it easy to turn a peerDep warning into an error.

There's also [this package](https://yarnpkg.com/package/check-peer-dependencies) you can run in CI for yarn v1:

```bash
npx check-peer-dependencies
```